# Browser Back Button keep Re-executing the Lightning Flow!

Tags: lightning, visual-workflow

I have a lightning action button that fires a flow which invokes some apex to do some validation and return a list message of success or failure.  All this works great as designed.  It simply pops up a message box with only the Finish button.  I click finish and everything is great.

However, then when I click the browser's back button the flow fires off again.  I can never get back via the browser!

How can I work around this issue to stop the browser from running the flow when I click the back button?  If I go the page but don't click the button and then click the back button I can go back without the flow being invoked.

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Because clicking the action changes the url, you have to mess with the browser history.  In the lwc that's executed by the action, replace the browser's history of the current page with the previous page.

```
const ref = document.referrer;

if (ref) {
    window.history.replaceState(null, null, ref);
}
```

Then when you press back, it will effectively go to the page you were on prior to the action.